# Using JetBrain's MPS to create an editor plugin

Tags: jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, mps

Can I use MPS to create a "conventional" language plugin for IntelliJ?

It looks like MPS' core feature is the transcription from a DSL to Java. However I just want to define the DSL syntax and editor to ship it as a standalone language plugin via the JetBrain plugin repository.

I am uncertain whether that is the purpose of MPS or I have to use the Grammar-Kit to create the plugin as it is described [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MPS allows you to create IDEA plugins, just like the Grammar-Kit does. Take the MPS route, if you need any of its core features - projectional editor, modular languages or multi-stage code generator.

Vaclav

Comment: What is a "MPS route"? I just found one MPS guide which goes into the wrong direction: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD31/Building+IntelliJ+IDEA+language+plugins

Comment: You discovered the correct page, although of an old MPS version. The up-to-date description of building MPS plugins for IDEA is at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD34/Building+IntelliJ+IDEA+language+plugins. Several plugins have already been built this way - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/92-mps/idea